# Waterline handling Exception

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have a User model where field username have to match a regular expression like this:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/g
```

When the username contains a special characters Waterline throw an Exception, it's right!

There is a way to know that is a Regular Expression Exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can find validations doc here 
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/validations.md 
Search for "***regex***"

Comment: Thanks for documentation